# Running scripts from OS X terminal instantly returns nothing

Tags: python, c++, macos, terminal, waf

I encountered this problem while trying to figure a waf file. `./waf configure --mode=release --with-python --with-cpptests --with-examples --with-vamp` as well as just `./waf` instantly returns nothing (when it should presumably show configure progress with the first command and an error because it is unconfigured for the second). I also attempted running a python script from the terminal `python ./scriptname.py` and it too returned nothing instead of running.

Last night, `./waf configure` was giving errors because multiple files could not be found. Since then, I have updated OS X, updated XCode, as well as re-installed a few dependencies for the python library I am attempting to install with the waf. I have been working on this all day and haven't yet figured out why running the scripts apparently does nothing; any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do non-Python things run correctly?

Comment: Actually yes, non-Python things do seem to run correctly. Strangely, running `what python` now gives `python: No such file or directory`.

Comment: What does `type python` print?

Comment: `type python` prints `python is /Users/alexforsyth/anaconda/bin/python` which is the same result `what python` used to return, but does not anymore.

Comment: Does running `python` with no filename yield the typical interactive prompt?

Comment: No, that returns nothing. This definitely seems like the problem is with Python.

Comment: It does. I would try uninstalling Anaconda, seeing if that works, then reinstalling it if you need its functionality. It’s possible an uninstall/reinstall cycle would fix it, and it would be worthwhile to see whether the Apple-distributed Python works while you’re doing that.

Comment: After reinstalling Anaconda, `type python` returns `python is hashed (/Users/alexforsyth/anaconda/bin/python)`

Comment: If it’s hashed, you might need to restart your shell (or use `hash -r`, but that doesn’t always work for me). Whether it’s hashed or not, though, the more interesting question is whether it works. It might also be useful to know whether it worked using the Apple Python (after uninstalling, but before reinstalling).

Comment: After restarting the terminal, I was able to run python scripts, so I think that fixes this problem thanks. After running the `./waf configure`, I get this message though: `Checking for library python2.7 in LIBPATH_PYEMBED : not found`. Along with multiple other `not found` messages.

Comment: Found the solution to that problem here: https://github.com/MTG/essentia/issues/43